# why Tasks idle for sometime while running Spark job

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

[image: captured screenshot from Executors tab]

I'm running spark job and noticed that after few stages completion, tasks were idle for sometime and again started.

Spark version - 2.2 and Java 1.8

Total  Nodes - 3(including master)

Total cores - 16(8 for each datanode)

Total memory - 16 GB(8 for each)

below is spark submit command I used.

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1G --executor-cores 2 --num-executors 6 --jars jar1  --class wordcount wordcount.jar
```

Is there any reason why tasks goes to idle state?. if yes,what could be the reason.

Please find the attached screen shot which shows no active tasks are running for sometime.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have some `group` operation and the result of this operation you see as a reduced number of partitions.

Also it can be a badly distributed job (bad in terms of data - some nodes / partitions are heavier than others and you need to await their completion to go to the next step).

Some code examples can help to make any sense of this UI screenshot, but as a possible solution - just walk thorough your code carefully and try to catch group / repartitioning operations, take care about your partitioning scheme - mb it's an expected behaviour in your case, and double check IO operations (yes, it's probably smth that you've already checked - but also happens sometimes).